# C# DataTable fields value structuring

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a Datatable in C# with 2 fields and the first fields has the Label and it's value as well in next rows. And the second field has the values only.

```
Field1  Field2
10th    Nick
Nick    John
11th    Marry
John    Andy
Marry   Sandy
12th    null
Andy    null
Sandy   null
```

Is there any way or logic I can apply to structure my data to upload in SQL table in format like below.

```
Class   Name
10th    Nick
11th    John
11th    Marry
12th    Andy
12th    Sandy
```

This data is just an example but I need to apply the logic in around million of rows with thousands of class label and looking for something which can pick the `field1` value one by one and then search that value in `field2`

If found - Add that in `Name` field
if not found -  Add that in `class` field

```
var list = new List<TempFieldList>();
foreach (DataRow row in ListTable.Rows)
{
    list.Add(new TempFieldList{
                field1 = row["Field1"].ToString(), 
                field2 = row["Field2"].ToString()
                });
}
foreach (DataRow row in ListTable.Rows)
        {
            var result = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.field2 == row["Field1"].ToString());
            //row.Dump();
            if(result != null )
                ResultTable.Rows.Add("");       
            else
                ResultTable.Rows.Add(row["Field1"].ToString(), null);   
        }
```

Any better way, or code? As what I was trying is not working unfortunately.

Comment: is the list of classnames finite?

Comment: Yes, field1, field2. I just created that temporary to search the value. Would love to see if you have any other suggestion. Also to note, if needed I can create 3rd field as well in main table with unique labels only as well if that helps in any better logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below pseudocode and you'll have a list of custom objects that have class & Names matched up.  Then you can loop through that inserting into the database.

```
List<string> classes = new List();
classes.add("10th");
class.add("11th"); //and so on
string currentClass = new String();

SomeObjectWithClassAndName obj = new SomeObjectWithClassAndName();
List<SomeObjectWithClassAndName> myList = new List();

foreach(DataRow row in yourDataTable)
{
   if(classes.Contains(row.Field<string>[1])
   {
      currentClass = row.Field<string>[1];
   }
   else{
      obj = new SomeObject..;
      obj.Class = currentClass;
      obj.Name = row.Field<string>[1];
      MyList.Add(obj);
   }
}
```

Comment: This didn't produced the expected output. I tested and the names order is not kept as it should be while skipped some

Comment: sorry, had a bug in there.  I've updated this line of code obj.Name = row.Field<string>[2]; to this obj.Name = row.Field<string>[1];

Comment: Awesome,. working like a charm! thank you very much. You made my day!